# For movies and tv series why is it okay to make a false advertisement by saying "This is a true story" when it is actually not?

Tags: advertisements, entertainment-law

In every opening scene of Fargo Season 3, it says that:

> This is a true story. At the request of the survivors, the names have been changed. Out of respect for the dead, the rest has been told exactly as it occurred."

However, as mentioned in several [websites](https://www.bustle.com/p/fargo-season-3-isnt-a-true-story-no-matter-what-that-disclaimer-says-52123), the story is fictional. Is this not a false advertisement, which is supposed to be illegal? Many people might not be very attracted to the series if it was not advertised as `based on true stories` and would not have paid to watch it.

So, is this totally fine? Are there no consequences? And, why is this not considered a false advertisement? Does the following example make sense?

> This sausage is made from beef (that is why you buy it) while it is actually pork.

sounds the same as saying:

> "the story in this movie is true" (that is why you buy it) while it is not?

Comment: I don't think "false advertising" applies to statements that aren't intended to be believed. Otherwise, Comedy Central would be out of business.

Comment: @user6726 Then what is the difference between saying "this sausage is made from beef" (that is why you buy it) while it is actually pork, and saying "this story is true" (that is why you would buy it) while it is not?

Comment: Art is different. You expect hyperbole and humor from Fargo, not from Hormel. There is no reasonable expectation that fictitious TV stories are true.

Comment: An interesting comparison is the lawsuit over the book *A Million Little Pieces*, which was marketed as a true account of the author's experiences, but was later shown to be fabricated in many details.  There's an analysis of the suit [here](http://supreme.findlaw.com/legal-commentary/the-lawsuits-over-james-freys-a-million-little-pieces-although-the-author-has-conceded-fabrication-the-suits-should-be-dismissed.html).  But the publisher settled that case, so we don't know how a court would have ruled.

Comment: Incidentally, in that case, the publisher offered refunds upon request, but received only [1700 requests](http://www.foxnews.com/story/2007/11/03/judge-approves-million-little-pieces-refund-settlement-for-disgruntled-readers.html) out of [several million copies sold](http://www.nytimes.com/2006/03/12/books/several-million-little-dollars.html?mcubz=0).  So it could be that even if there is potential legal liability, FX may feel that the damages would be negligible.

Comment: Damages are very hard to prove, even in a clear-cut case. It's possible they settled over Million not because they thought they would lose, but because settling was cheaper than the legal fees they would have incurred fighting it. With FX and Fargo, I can't see any liability or realistic claim of damages.

Comment: Compare a novel that begins, “What I am about to tell you is strange, but I swear that I saw it all with my own eyes.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question!  It's actually *every* episode of all three seasons of Fargo, as I recall.

- Fargo is not an advertisement.  It is fictional content.  You can say whatever your want in creative work, particularly in the US, so long as you're not violating copyright law.

*(False advertising is kind of wiggly, in that I often see or hear advertisements all the time for supplements that claim to have some benefit or effect, with the disclaimer to the effect of "this claims have not been evaluated by the FDA" or some such.  In other words, you can potentially lie in an advertisement so long as you admit the claims have no scientific basis;)*

---

Regarding @Nate Eldredge's excellent point about Million Little Pieces, in that case they were claiming a fictional story was true as a sales technique in reference to a biography.

In the case of Fargo, it is clearly not meant to be taken literally.  (Satire and other forms of "lies" are protected by free speech in the US.)

The original Fargo movie, from which this tradition re: Fargo the series derives, may even have had a disclaimer in the end credits "This is a work of fiction...", etc.  This does make me want to review the end credits for the show as well.  Creativity is one thing, but the studios are mega-conglomerates and therefore obsessed with potential liability.

Comment: But the whole point is that the work (ostensibly) claims to **not** be fictional content.  The link in my comment above discusses cases where works claiming to be non-fictional were found to contain fictional statements, and publishers were sued.  Those cases were settled; by your logic you would have expected them to simply be dismissed.  So I am not sure it is as simple as your answer suggests.

Comment: I was just going back in to address your excellent comment about "Million Little Pieces".  Very distinct case from Fargo, imo.

Comment: What would you say are the major indications that would make it clear to a reasonable person that the "true story" claim is not to be taken literally?

Comment: @NateEldredge "Out of respect for the dead, the rest has been told exactly as it occurred."  is technically impossible.  Even a faithful biopic of a real person takes all kinds of liberties, and there are events depicted all over Fargo which could never be validated.  (Scenes involving a solo person who later dies or disappears, like Hanzee in S2.  Plenty of scenes of Hanzee solo.)

Comment: @NateEldredge Also the fact that the introduction is clearly [a reference to a prior creative work.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Fargo_(film))